# How to ignorecase for input string

Tags: python, string, substring, ignore-case

Here is my sample code I'm learning. I want to take a string (1 or more characters) and compare it against the existing string. I want to enter **blue** and still get the answer. How to ignore the case completely?
Thanks.

```
parrot = "Norwegian Blue"

letter = input("Enter a character: ")

if letter in parrot:
    print("The letter {0} is in the Norwegian Blue".format(letter))
else:
    print("Sorry the letter is missing ")
```

for a success case:

```
C:\PythonMasterClass>python IfProgramFlow.py  
Enter a character: Blue  
The letter Blue is in the Norwegian Blue
```

and for the failed case:

```
C:\PythonMasterClass>python IfProgramFlow.py  
Enter a character: blue  
Sorry the letter is missing
```

I've checked other threads to convert my inputs and actual text to lower case and compare against, but I wanted a straight way.
What If I have multiple strings, I don't want to save all of them in lower case for this purpose.
Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Try: `if letter.lower() in parrot.lower():`

Comment: Saw that this morning, I just wanted to get a straight way like in Java to match the string. Thanks.